# How to embed vuejs code into other website

Tags: vue.js

I have developed a small App in VueJs and now I want to integrate this app into another website. I know there are ways using iframe/embed, but I need something similar to Google analytics code, meaning it just gives us few lines of JS code and it does all the trick.

Is it possible to create a JS code, add it to another website, and that website start displaying my VueJs application serving from another host?

Comment: never tried it, most likely it wouldn't work because of relative paths etc, but you could try using `splitChunks: false` on the build, then make a loader script that embeds the rendered/built dom onto the external site

Comment: Have you considered custom elements -> web components? This is scoped and won't interact with other JS. https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html.
A demonstration can be found here: https://maximomussini.com/posts/vue-custom-elements.